# Index.html file not opening in browser

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code, browser, launch

I created a project with Angular framework using Visual Studio Code. My project is launching on browser when I use "ng serve" command in CLI. But the final index.html file generated in dist folder after "ng build" is not opening on browser when I try to open it from file location. Why?

So index.html file in dist folder can't be opened from file location by double clicking on it?

[Opened with ng serve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbDHZ.png)

[Opened from file location by double clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBSJH.png)

[File location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0U1S.png)

Comment: Such programs need to be run via a web server ONLY. Therefore won't work by double clicking it as the page is not "static"

Comment: Such issues can actually be found by a simple google search, please use this site for more "specific" debugging related questions or the ones you cannot find answers to.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot run an Angular app by opening the index.html
the app must be hosted on a Web Server (local or remote).
You can build your own webserver using node (for example express.js) or use NGINX on a server online.